# Unexpected Apple ID password prompt - Which App is causing this?

Tags: ios, apple-id, password, dialog

I am getting unexpected prompts for my Apple ID on my iPhone SE at random times, including on the lock screen. Here are a couple of examples:

On the lock screen

[image]

In the EMail app

[image]

These started appearing a couple of weeks ago.  The prompt dialogs have no identifying information to tell me who's asking, so I'm not about to enter my Apple password until I know who's asking and why.

I have correlated these to having one specific app either running or configured for background refresh.  If the app is closed and background refresh is disabled, I do not seem to get the prompts.

The app is Appigo ToDo, which has a cloud-based component that *does* require sign-in.  However,

1. I am already signed in correctly to ToDo Cloud, and if I just dismiss the prompt (Cancel) without entering anything I get no error, and ToDo Cloud proceeds with no issues;
2. If I enter my password for ToDo Cloud, the error message is

[image]

So, *something*, possibly related to Appigo ToDo Cloud, is asking for my APPLE password.

Question(s): Given a password prompt dialog, is there any way to determine the source of the request, and the reason for the request?  What else could be causing iOS to be prompting for my Apple password at random times?

Comment: Have you tried deleting and reinstalling the App?

Comment: Yes, the same password prompt appeared immediately upon launching the app to its "welcome" screen. So it appears the app is quite likely to be the culprit.  I have deleted the app again and will wait a few days to see if I get any more prompts.  They've been appearing at least once a day, so 2-3 days should be enough.  Although at this point I'm 95% certain it's the app, and I have filed a ticket with Appigo Support.

Comment: Will look more into it. FYI I’m pretty sure if you press the Home button and it does not exist then it is a legitimate Apple ID prompt.

Comment: Did you originally install that app with a different Apple ID?  Maybe as part of family sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this snippet from [this help page](http://support.appigo.com/support/solutions/articles/143961-synchronizing-todo-using-icloud) at Appigo will provide a clue:

> iCloud is different from the other synchronization services supported by Todo in that Todo does not actively control when synchronization takes place. When you make changes to your tasks Todo flags its data as having changed; iCloud watches for this flag and synchronizes as needed. In short, while Todo can inform iCloud that it needs to be synchronized, it cannot start or control an active synchronization.

I think that ToDo needs you to manually login to iCloud, **which uses your Apple ID for authentication**, to sync because the saved password is incorrect. Perhaps you need to reconfirm the login credentials within the ToDo app so it syncs correctly.